# How to get the phone number not the country code in MuiPhoneNumber in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MuiPhoneNumber library in order to get the country code and then to add the number, but when I submit the value this field only returns the country code.

```
<MuiPhoneNumber
              fullWidth
              defaultCountry={"de"}
              value={formik.values.phone}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
              helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
            />
```

value of the formik.values.phone is "DE", when i have put the number, how to get the number not the country code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MuiPhoneNumber` comes from the library [`material-ui-phone-number`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number) the `onChange` event is called with the actual value but formik expects an event. You need to imperatively set the value yourself using [`setFieldValue`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void).

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number";

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { phone: "" },
    onSubmit: (values) => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <MuiPhoneNumber
        fullWidth
        defaultCountry={"de"}
        value={formik.values.phone}
        onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("phone", value)}
        error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
        helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit small-lake-xngqq7]

But this doesn't explain why you have the country code in your formik values. It certainly can't come from anything you entered into the `MuiPhoneNumber` field as you didn't connect it properly.